# why it so important do disable THP ( transparent huge pages ) on database servers?

Tags: linux, rhel, kernel, memory, huge-pages

We have hadoop cluster

We notice that on many DB servers, that the THPs are disabled ( include HDFS servers )

Can you explain why it is so important to disable THP on DB servers?

what could be if THP is enabled?, on DB servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends on the workload and THP mostly gives worse performance. A good article is at [Percona](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/03/06/settling-the-myth-of-transparent-hugepages-for-databases/)